# how to rotate a vector based map?

Tags: javascript, rotation, html5-canvas

I need to rotate a map which has been drawn based on a vector map with using CANVAS.I will use this map in a navigation system which runs in browser.Is there any simple way to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the [`context.rotate(angle)`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/2dcontext/html5_canvas/#transformations) method. This method does not affect what is currently drawn on the canvas, but instead affects everything which will be drawn to it after setting the rotation. The angle is in radians, so a full circle is pi * 2 = 6.28318530718.

The rotation will be around the point 0:0 of the current internal coordinate system of the canvas. I would recommend you to use [`context.translate(x, y)`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/2dcontext/html5_canvas/#dom-context-2d-translate) to place this in the center of your canvas instead of the upper-left corner.

1. draw the map on an invisible background canvas
2. set transformation on the visible canvas to the rotation-center
3. set the rotation on a visible canvas
4. use `drawImage` to draw the invisible canvas to the visible one (when you use drawImage, the source can also be another canvas). This drawImage call will be affected by the rotation and translation you set.

When you have control over when and how the original map is drawn, you can alternatively apply the transformation and rotation to the original canvas before drawing it.

Comment: I implemented first three steps but i could not the last one.Can you help me?
Here is my source code:

    var visibleCanvas = document.getElementById("VisibleCanvas");
    var visibleCtx = visibleCanvas.getContext("2d");
    visibleCtx.translate(400,300);
    visibleCtx.rotate(Math.PI);
    visibleCtx.drawImage(c,-400,-300,800,600);


c is my hidden canvas.

Comment: @mekafe Please create a new question, post your code there (preferably as a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)) and explain exactly where your are stuck (what you expect to happen and what happens instead).